# Modify layout margin then generate an image from this layout

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have a weird problem,

I have an activity, within this activity I have a layout I want to make an image of it in order to share it on social networks. 
This layout contains differents dynamic images and texts. That's why I can't just store it on as a static image and share it on demand. I need to generate the image right when the user touch the share button.

The problem is that I need to adjust the layout before sharing, what I do ?

```
    ImageView profilPic = (ImageView)dashboardView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)profilPic.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(10, 62, 0, 0);
    profilPic.invalidate();
    profilPic.requestLayout();
```

First I modify the margin of my layout, then I make an image of it

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;   
        try {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dashboardView.getWidth(),
                    dashboardView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
            dashboardView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Logger.e(e.toString());
        }

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        File path = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, "wayzupDashboard" + ".png");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        try {
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And finally I share it.

Basically it works, except that it captures the layout BEFORE redrawing the layout with modified layoutParams.
I need to capture this layout once and only when the new layout parameters are took into account, after layout is redraw.

If I remove the capture code, well it works, when I touch the share button I see the layout moving. But when I have the capture code in place it just capture the layout before modifying margins.

How can I ensure that the layout is redraw before capturing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, to correctly capture the layout only once the view was setup I needed to first setup the view and then capture the layout in a delayed thread. This is the only way I found to make it works.

```
public void onShareButton() {
        dashboardController.setupViewBeforeSharing();

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;   
                try {
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dashboardView.getWidth(),
                            dashboardView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                    dashboardView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Logger.e(e.toString());
                }

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                File path = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(path, "wayzupDashboard" + ".png");
                try {
                    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
                try {
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image/png");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, R.string.addPassengerButton);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image"));

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        dashboardController.setupViewAfterSharing();   
                    }
                });

            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way, is to set-up a listener for layout pass on the `dashboardView` view. 
Setting-up listener using `View.addOnLayoutChangeListener()` - [addOnLayoutChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnLayoutChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener%29).

Set the listener **before** changing the layout parameters and remove it **after** the image was saved to persistence. 
Hope it'll add any improvement.